# New window size

Tags: javascript, html, size

I know that this question is been asked tons of times, but I'm asking not exactly that. This code belongs to website menu bar, so I have to keep this code, otherwise design would be totally different.
Code:

```
<li class="removable-parent">
<a class="removable-parent" href="http://88.88.209.56:12/player.html" data-
link-type="EXTERNAL"  target= "_blank"> 
<span id="4884dd90"  class="preview-element Link item-link magic-circle-
holder text-element custom" data-menu-name="PREVIEW_LINK" >Spiller</span>
</a>
<script>
function clickHandler() {
window.open(this.href, "_blank", "width=640,height=480");
return false; // to prevent default action.
 } document.getElementById("http://88.88.209.56:12/player.html").onclick=clickHandler
  }
</script>
</li>
```

So how can I make that this code opens window in decided size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use javascript.

Get a reference to your  object and handle the click event. In that event, use window.open with the proper parameters to set the width and height of your pop-up window.

Make sure you cancel the original event so you don't end up with two pop-ups.

Something like:

```
<script>
     function clickHandler() {
        window.open(this.href, "_blank", "width=640,height=480");
        return false; // to prevent default action.
    }

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".removable-parent");
    for (var i = 0, elem; elem = elems[i]; ++i) {
        elem.onclick = clickHandler;
    }
</script>
```

Or, if you wish to apply this behavior on one link, first add an id attribute to your link:

```
<a class="removable-parent" id="myelement" href="http://88.88.209.56:12/player.html" data-link-type="EXTERNAL" target= "_blank">
```

The script should then be simplified so it applies only on that element:

```
<script>
    function clickHandler() {
        window.open(this.href, "_blank", "width=640,height=480");
        return false; // to prevent default action.
    }
    document.getElementById("myelement").onclick = clickHandler;
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please write how the haul code should look like, because I'm really bad at this.

Comment: @Beginner: Answer updated, you just need to copy that block at the end of your page, or in an external script that runs once the page is loaded.

Comment: Hi, I just saw that this make to all web page menus. How can I make so that do only for this one?

Comment: Add an id to this one: <a href=... id="mylink">. Then replace whole the second part of the script by document.getElementById("mylink").onclick=clickHandler

Comment: It does not work. Maybe I did something wrong. I updated code. If you could take a look at my code that is above, and say what I did wrong.

Comment: No, you need to add an id to your <a> tag. In my example, I named the id "mytag". In your code, you used the href as id, that will not work. I edited my answer to show the full code for single link.